# Gatling feeder that passes same data to each user every x seconds

Tags: gatling

I'd like to pass several items to each user, say a csv that looks like

```
"name1","value1"
"name2","value2"
...
"name10","value10"
```

so if three users are ramped up, each one would be fed ten pairs, in this order, and would execute a request using these values every 5 seconds.

My current code is

```
 csv("data/values.csv").circular();
...
scenario("Get Test")
        .forever().on(
            pace(5)
                .feed(feeder)
                .exec(
                    range(0, 10)
                        .mapToObj(ReportSimulation::getDataUsingLineIndex)
                        .collect(toList())
                )
        )
```

However this doesn't seem to execute the GET request every 5 seconds for each index and each user. Is there an option to achieve this in gatling?

Comment: "this doesn't seem to..." You have described the desired behaviour, so what is the observed behaviour?